# Discord.js command handling isn't working for me

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I created a Discord.js bot, i wanted to separate each commands with **fs**, like ./commands/ping.js.
It worked, but idk why, an hour later it went down.I didn't to aníthing with the bot, and nobody can access the code - of course -.
The bot works and there isn't error message. The events, like ready and messages are working too, but the commands, what are DIRECTLY IN FILES, aren't working. So for example, it messages, that "BOT started", but the ping.js isn't working.

Here is the index.js, but if you need anything else to debug, please comment!

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));


for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

fs.readdir('./events/', (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    const eventHandler = require(`./events/${file}`)
    const eventName = file.split('.')[0]
    client.on(eventName, (...args) => eventHandler(client, ...args))
  })
})

client.login(token);
```

Thanks for all! ~Akos

Comment: Could you show ping.js? also are other commands working?

Comment: Could you also show ./events/message.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kian Here,

This should work for you :). I've tried to leave some comments so you can understand the code, if you have any issues with this code, chuck a comment and ill edit the code to make it work

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {

    // check for errors
    if (err) console.log(err);

    // get name of file
    let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");

    // if it cannot find any commands
    if (jsfile.length <= 0) {
        console.log("Couldn't find commands.");
        return;
    }

    // log the amount of files
    console.log(`Loading ${jsfile.length} commands!`);

    // load the command
    jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
        // grab the module.exports from the file
        let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
        console.log(`${i+1}: ${f} loaded!`);
        client.commands.set(props.name, props);
    });
});

// apparently this works so i'll leave it chief :)
fs.readdir('./events/', (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
        const eventHandler = require(`./events/${file}`)
        const eventName = file.split('.')[0]
        client.on(eventName, (...args) => eventHandler(client, ...args))
    })
})

client.login(token);
```

Have a good one ~ Unkwn